# distributed transaction .net java SAP

Tags: java, .net, transactions, soa, distributed

I use several systems connected by Service oriented architecture, those systems include : .NET technology, Java WebLogic Service, and SAP RFC.

is it possible to achieve distributed transaction across these different technologies ? for example when updating SAP failed, we need to make sure that .NET, and Java transaction won't happen at all.

Really appreciate your input, or maybe you can point out where we can learn the basics how to do it?

Comment: what is the language of the driver program that make calls to these three different services?

Comment: mainly these services will be called from .NET

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as follows:

1. Each interaction with the service is a [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) with `execute()` and `undo()` methods defined.
2. Maintain a stack of commands, push each command once it is successful.
3. When a command fails, i.e. interaction with a service fails, pop each command from the stack and call `undo()`.

You might look for any [Distributed Transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction) APIs in .NET that would provide this functionality out of the box, though.

Comment: Hi Vikdor, thanks for your quick reply. Does it mean that we need to implement "undo" method manually? is there any out of the box API in .net, java, or SAP RFC which will support this rollback operation and can communicate with .net to synchronize commit/rollback of transaction ?

Comment: The undo operation for a service call is very specific to that call and hence may not be supported by any framework out of the box. Same argument applies to SAP call as well. Yeah, a framework might handle database interactions by providing undo wherein the db operation's transaction will be rolled back. Let's see what C# experts have to say about any existing frameworks that offer this functionality ...

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using distributed transactions between systems as it creates a lot of coupling between them and increases the load on each system as it holds locks for the others (you can see a write up I did on this called ["transactional integration anti-pattern"](http://arnon.me/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/TransactionalIntegration.pdf)).
Usually a better option, as suggested by Vikdor is using a [Saga](http://rgoarchitects.bit.ly/4xNwpp) which you can coordinate manually or by some external coordinator (e.g. using [Orchestration](http://arnon.me/soa-patterns/Orchestration/)).

Note that compensation logic might not be able to completely undo the operation (e.g. in a retail scenario, if an order caused you to hit an inventory threshold and order from your supplier a cancellation of that order doesn't have to cancel your order from your supplier. Also you may not refund the full sum etc. )

Comment: Hi Arnon, Thanks a lot for your answer. You definitely give us some materials where we can start to learn. We recently got some concern about "rollback" operation because we can't guarantee that our rollback operation will sucess.

Comment: I sometimes find it is useful to do reservations (http://rgoarchitects.bit.ly/5NILfx) to rollback operations independently on the service side if the whole Saga doesn't finish fast enough (e.g. and you want to make sure you can still undo the operation)